# How do I call a function of a deployed smart contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

How do I call a function of a deployed smart contract?
Here is the deployed contract with a call function having two input parameters - user address and email id and it returns the user details. How do I make a new smart contract which gets the user details from a deployed smart contract without giving any input parameter (in this case - user address and email id)?

```
  //deployed contract
  struct User  {
      
    address  wallet_address;  
    string  userId;
    string  first_name;
    string  last_name;
    string  email_id;
    bool set;
    string private_key;

  }
 

  mapping(address => User)  users; 
  mapping(string => address) walletAccount;
  mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;

  function getUser(address _userAddress,string memory _emailId) public view returns(address,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory){
      
       User memory user = users[_userAddress];
       
       
     
       return(users[_userAddress].wallet_address,users[_userAddress].userId,users[_userAddress].first_name,users[_userAddress].last_name,users[_userAddress].email_id,users[_userAddress].private_key);
         
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You can send JSON RPC requests to the blockchain. For example:

```
"from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
"to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675",
"gas": "0x76c0", // 30400,
"gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
"value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
"data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
```

Your function call details is in the `data` parameter.

This is the very manual way.

2. There is some libraries like [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) or [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/). You can look at them, if you call your function programatically.
3. You can also call [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) or truffle etc. Google it like: remix call a deployed contract.